# What can we get from the square integrability of the derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $f$ be a continuously differentiable function on $[1, +\infty]$.

**Question:** Is it true that $\int_1^{+\infty} (f')^2dx < +\infty$ implies $\int_1^{+\infty} (\frac f x)^2 dx< +\infty$?

This is the integral version of the question in this post: [If a positive series converge in square sum, will its average series converge in square sum?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3877492/if-a-positive-series-converge-in-square-sum-will-its-average-series-converge-in).

I am interested in this question because it seems rather simple and concrete. I think there should be some techniques to deal with such kind of problems. However, I am not able to prove or give a counterexample of the claim.

**What I have got:** (1) The claim holds when $f$ is a power function. (2) The claim fails if 'square integrability' of $f'$ and $\frac f x$ is replaced by 'absolute integrability', since $f$ can be chosen to be a constant $1$.

Comment: This seems to be related to Hardy inequalities ($\leftarrow$ google keyword), but I cannot find this result

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thank you so much. This is exactly [Hardy inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3456449/hardy-inequality). Would you mind posting the comment as an answer?

Comment: No, not exactly, it is not starting from $1$, and the derivative might not be positive (which seems required in dimension $1$)

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126889/computing-the-best-constant-in-classical-hardys-inequality) may also be a good link but I don't have the time to go through the proofs atm

Comment: @LL3.14 I see it now. It is not mentioned in the link in my previous comment that the derivative needs to be positive.

Comment: In the link you mentionned, the derivative is called $f$ (what you call $f'$ here). Of course it has to be positive (if not, $f^p$ might be a complex number). However, similar proof as the usual Hardy inequality gives a similar answer (see my answer). Remark that the $f(1)$ is added, so it is different from Hardy's inequality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have an inequality similar to Hardy's inequality:
$$
\boxed{\left\|\frac{f(x)}{x}\right\|_{L^2[1,\infty)} ≤ f(1) + 2 \left\|f'\right\|_{L^2[1,\infty)}}
$$

*Proof:* First remark that
$$
∫_1^\infty \left|\frac{f(x)}{x}\right|^2\mathrm d x = \left\|\frac{1}{x} \left(f(1)+ \int_1^x f'\right)\right\|_{L^2[1,\infty)}^2
\\
≤ \left(\left\|\frac{f(1)}{x}\right\|_{L^2[1,\infty)} + \left\|\frac{1}{x} \int_1^x f'\right\|_{L^2[1,\infty)}\right)^2 
$$
and the first integral is easily bounded since
$$
\left\|\frac{f(1)}{x}\right\|_{L^2[1,\infty)} = f(1) \left(\int_1^\infty x^{-2}\,\mathrm d x\right)^{1/2} = f(1)
$$
To bound the second integral, we can do the same strategy as for the classical [Hardy's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%27s_inequality) and use first a change of variable $t= sx$ to get
$$
\left\|\frac{1}{x} \int_1^x f'(t)\,\mathrm d t\right\|_{L^2[1,\infty)}
 = \left\|\int_{1/x}^1 f'(sx)\,\mathrm d s\right\|_{L^2[1,\infty)}
\\
= \left\|\int_0^1 \mathbf{1}_{\{s>1/x\}} f'(sx)\,\mathrm d s\right\|_{L^2_x[1,\infty)}
\\
≤ \int_0^1 \left\| \mathbf{1}_{\{sx>1\}} f'(sx)\right\|_{L^2_x[1,\infty)} \,\mathrm d s
$$
and then a second change of variable giving
$$
\int_0^1 \left\| \mathbf{1}_{\{sx>1\}} f'(sx)\right\|_{L^2_x[1,\infty)} \,\mathrm d s = \int_0^1 \left(\int_1^\infty |\mathbf{1}_{\{sx>1\}} f'(sx)|^2\,\mathrm d x\right)^{1/2} \,\mathrm d s
\\
= \int_0^1 \left(\int_{s}^\infty |\mathbf{1}_{\{y>1\}} f'(y)|^2\,\,\mathrm d y\right)^{1/2} s^{-1/2}\,\mathrm d s
\\
= \int_0^1 \left(\int_{1}^\infty |f'(y)|^2\,\,\mathrm d y\right)^{1/2} s^{-1/2}\,\mathrm d s = 2 \|f'\|_{L^2[1,\infty)}
$$
Therefore
$$
∫_1^\infty \left|\frac{f(x)}{x}\right|^2\mathrm d x ≤ \left(f(1) + 2 \left\|f'\right\|_{L^2[1,\infty)}\right)^2 
$$

Comment: Of course not, the primitive of $s^{-1/2}$ is $2s^{1/2}$ ... the global criterion is that $s^a$ is integrable near $0$ iff $a>-1$.

Comment: I added a step to clarify. Since there is the indicator function and $s<1$, the integral just starts from $1$ in any cases.

Comment: It seems $f'$ being positive is not essential even if the integral in the question is from $0$ to $+\infty$ as long as $f(0) = 0$. Is it true that even if $f'$ is signed, Hardy Inequality still holds as long as $p$ is chosen that $(f')^p$ is not a complex number?

Comment: It might just be true by taking $|f'|^p$ I suppose.